# Is there an R function to change my string day variable and my numeric time variable into a single numeric hours variable?

Tags: r, date

I'm looking to combine two variables, day and time into a single variable consisting of hours out of 168 in a week. For example, my day variable reads "Tuesday" and the time reads "13:00". Is there a way to merge these to give me a variable consisting of the numeric value of hours out of 168 in the week? (E.g, the Tuesday 13:00 changed to 37).

Simple in theory but I can't quite figure out the best way to go about this for a bulk amount of data. I'm assuming using lubridate?

Or would it simply be easier to create a new variable and manually add this data?

Comment: Please include a sample of data in the form you're working with, often easiest by sharing the output of `dput(head(YOUR_TABLE))` in the body of your question. That reduces ambiguities and makes it easier for people to help you.

Comment: What is the expected behavior if the time includes minutes (eg "13:27")?

Comment: @LMc I need the minutes to output as a decimal of the hour

Comment: So in that case you'd expect the decimal to be `27/60=0.45`?

Comment: @LMc Yeah, so I need my overall output to be 37.45

Answer (score 2):

We may do a `match` and then multiply by `24` and add the remaining hours

```
library(lubridate)
day <- "Tuesday"
hour <- "13:00"
time <- lubridate::hms(paste0(hour, ":00"))
dayind <- match(day, 
       c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
        "Saturday", "Sunday"))
(dayind-1) * 24 + hour(time) + minute(time)/60
[1] 37

[1] 37
```

Comment: just a heads up about the comments in the question when dealing with minutes.